# How to set activity indicator view in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

In `.h` file:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *mySpinner;
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
mySpinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
mySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mySpinner];
```

and finally I am calling it on button click as:

```
[mySpinner startAnimating];
```

The problem is that when I called it in `viewDidLoad` it showed and start animating but didn't animate on button click not even show. Help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can You check that button click function is called?  (for example in button click function add NSLog(@"called button click!");  and check console output if You see that message once You click on button.

Comment: yes button click is called perfectly… i checked it in NSLog

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in your button click method, does Xcode stop when you click the button?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes it stops...

Comment: @MichaelDautermann its still give me the same result as before.

Comment: on button click can You try:

[mySpinner stopAnimating];
and then [mySpinner startAnimating];

 ?

Also - Do You use ARC ?

Comment: @GuntisTreulands  yes i tried it as you said… and i think in xcode5 no need to set ARC, it is automatically being used. am i right??

Comment: @Zaibi, correct. ARC is set to YES by default.

Would it be possible that You send me Your project? is that a fresh project You just started on? or is it already existing private/confidentional project?  Would it be possible that You create a fresh project (single view based), implement this functionality, and test it ? to make sure it really does not work?

Comment: @GuntisTreulands yes its confidential …. and let me try with a new test project..

Comment: @GuntisTreulands :( no it didn't work even in a new project.

Comment: Great! Can You zip it and send it to me? gtreulands@gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47678/discussion-between-guntis-treulands-and-zaibi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyOne who helped me ….
I have resolved the issue and here i am posting the answer for some one who is in search of this… actually the issue is "i am Downloading some records on synchronous request. So thats why UI Updation is blocked for a while.

so this is creating problem here….

On Button click i just make a new thread that call a method    'start'

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(Start) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and the 'start' method is

```
- (void) Start
{
Spinner.hidden = NO;
[mySpinner startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I have used ur solution it works also but my problem is whenever app goes background and then foreground then activityindicator stop animating. u know what is the reason? also same thing not happen when I start activityIndicator in viewDidLoad Method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your '`mySpinner`" ivar isn't being properly retained or declared.

In your .h file, declare it as a **property**.  That is:

```
@property (strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *mySpinner;
```

then, when you create it:

```
self.mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

and when you reference it in your button click method:

```
[self.mySpinner startAnimating];
```